# Simulate Mouse Click when key is pressed

Tags: c#, mouseclick-event, onkeypress

I´m trying to simulate a mouse click when certain key is pressed.

I tried this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);

private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x08; 

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
         case Keys.Insert:

             Point pt = Cursor.Position;
             int X = Cursor.Position.X;
             int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;

             mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN, X, Y, 0, 0);
             break;
    }
```

It doesn't seems to be working, and I couldn't find any other solution.

Comment: That event will be called only when your application is on the foreground. Is that your intention?

Comment: To simulate the click you probably need to do `MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP` after `MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN`. And  the up one is `0x10` instead of `0x08`

Comment: Can't you just call the mouse-click handler method from the key-handler, or is there a special reason to do it this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure the Form `KeyPreview` property is set to **True**

[image]

To do the click simulation you need to call `MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN` and `MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP` like so. *(also notice i use uint along the way)*

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint cButtons, uint dwExtraInfo);

private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Insert:

            int X = Cursor.Position.X;
            int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;

            mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP, (uint)X, (uint)Y, 0, 0);
            break;
    }
}
```